# How to get profile pictures from instagram

Tags: graphql, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

H,
for a project, I need to get the profile picture from the URL of an Instagram user.

I can get it by [www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](http://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1)
but since it's not documented and googling reveals that this may violate the terms I'm currently looking for an alternative.
The backend would query the pictures and I can't require every account to manually allow usage of the profile picture. Is there a nice graphql(8/9) way of doing this? It works perfectly with FB
I would welcome pointers in the right direction.

Thanks,
Hellfiend